# Dynamic cron jobs in NestJs

Tags: cron, nestjs

How to schedule cron job that run every Monday on next hours:

```
1 week - 6:00
2 week - 7:00
3 week - 8:00
...
n - 1 week 18:00
n week 19:00
n + 1 week 6:00
n + 2 week 7:00
```

I was try this one, but it doesn't work correctly

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsCron implements OnModuleInit {
constructor(
    private schedulerRegistry: SchedulerRegistry,
  ) {}

  private readonly dynamicProductsSuggestionCronJobName = 'DynamicProductsSuggestionCronJob';
  private hour = 6;

  private setCronSchedule(hour: number) {
    try {
      this.schedulerRegistry.deleteCronJob(this.dynamicProductsSuggestionCronJobName);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`${this.dynamicProductsSuggestionCronJobName} not found.`);
    }

    const job = new CronJob(`* */${hour} * * * 1`, () => {
      this.suggestShifts(String(hour));
      this.hour = this.hour < 19 ? this.hour + 1 : 6;
      this.setCronSchedule(this.hour);
    });
    this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob(this.dynamicProductsSuggestionCronJobName, job);
    job.start();
  }

  public onModuleInit() {
    this.setCronSchedule(this.hour);
  }
}
```